# User input in perl - Issue with running script in KomodoEdit

Tags: perl, komodo

i wrote this tiny code on gedit and ran it :-

```
#/usr/bin/perl
print "Enter the radius of circle: \n";
$radius = <>;
chomp $radius;
print "radius is: $radius\n";
$circumference = (2*3.141592654) * $radius;
print "Circumference of circle with radius : $radius = $circumference\n";
```

Runs fine using command line.Ran the same code on Komodo Edit: facing an issue i expect first line as output as :- Enter the radius of circle: whearas it waits on the screen i.e waiting for an input and after that runs everything in sequence -- can someone tell me why it runs fine with command line but not Komodo?

---

output after changing  #/usr/bin/perl to  #!/usr/bin/perl:- also had to declare my $radius and my $circumference ----------------------------------------------------------

```
12 # same i had to enter 12
Enter the radius of circle: 
radius is: 12
Circumference of circle with radius : 12 = 75.398223696
```

Comment: correct the first line first, it should be '#!/usr/bin/perl'

Comment: output after changing as you mentioned:- 
also had to declare my $radius and my $circumference
----------------------------------------------------------
12 # same i had to enter 12 

Enter the radius of circle: 

radius is: 12

Circumference of circle with radius : 12 = 75.398223696

Comment: this is correct, what is the error you are facing with Komodo edit.

Comment: You appear to be a new Perl programmer. A quick tip: *always* start every file with `use strict; use warnings;` -- it will save you lots of pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While 'use strict' and a correctly spelled shebang line are always good things,
neither is the actual cause.  When you run an interactive program in a
non-command-line environment, you should usually turn off I/O buffering.
In Perl you should put this line at the top of your code:

```
$| = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your script using Komodo edit and it works fine other then below few corrections.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

print "Enter the radius of circle: \n";
my $radius = <>;
chomp $radius;
print "radius is: $radius\n";
my $circumference = (2*3.141592654) * $radius;
print "Circumference of circle with radius : $radius = $circumference\n";
```

Output in Komodo

```
Enter the radius of circle: 
5
radius is: 5
Circumference of circle with radius : 5 = 31.41592654
```

Comment: @ Ether - yes i am new to perl and i will keep your advice in mind thanks
@Octopus - Thanks for checking it 

Thanks a lot all - this kind of help gives a beginner the confidence that someone can help :)

Comment: Its funny but it doesn't work in Komodo - it works fine through command line -- it just waits for the input for some reason - may its about some setting in Komodo. :)